What is the Problem with Streamlit aggrid table formatting?
from st_aggrid import AgGrid
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json")
grid_return = AgGrid(df)

This is the picture of what it should look like:

but when I use the same code it look like this:

Can anyone tell me what happened here why its happening? I did multiple work by using height width things and changing its style but still it's not working properly.
I am working on streamlit aggrid code a very simple code but table formatting is not ok or working properly.
